ESP32 Schematic review, can't flash using U0TXD U0RXD
Hello 
I'm reaching for help, i tried debugging the issue with my current knowledge but to no avail...
I have created a ESP32-D0WD-V3 based board, It's pretty basic and cover what i need in a single PCB.

It has Power Inputs (5v/12v) that are regulated to 3.3v
RS485 (MaxLinear SP3485EN-L/TR)
USB to Serial (CH340X)
Ethernet

I ordered the PCBs preassembled from JLCPCB, unfortunately when i plugged it in i can see my Serial Chip CH340X but its completly silent even when using chip_pu to reboot the esp chip.
esptool.py cant communicate with the chip either.
Sample output with --trace
esptool.py v4.7.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting...TRACE +0.000 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes: 
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.100 No serial data received.

This is the schematic of the relevant parts :

What i have tried :

I have removed the two LEDs close to RS485 chip to "Disable" the resistors that could interfere with RX TX Lines.
I have removed the FLASH SPI (I thought since it was empty maybe it was trying to load the bootloader from there, but turns out from what i have read the "Factory Bootloader" is on the internal ROM)
Soldering an External NodeMCU used with EN & GND Shorted to use it as a Programmer
Using the GPIO0 Button to "force it" into Download Mode since i wasn't sure of my CH340X wiring.
Removed the RS485 chip and trying to flash it with usb and NodeMCU (Since you aren't supposed to have two devices on UART
Removed the RS485 and CH340X chip and trying to flash it with usb and NodeMCU
Bypassing my power circuits and using the nodemcu power lines.

I don't know what to do now...
The likelyhood that the 3 PCBs i went through came with defective chips from LCSC is highly unlikely...
I still have 2 untouched & never plugged PCBs if needed

The first thing to check is power at the chip VCC. Have you tried to hook up a scope to the serial to see if there is data going though?

Power is unlikely to be the issue, as tested (with a multimeter) the 12V, 5v and 3.3v power rails, during boot and reboot, everything is reading as expected. (no dips or unexpected spikes), i didn't test it directly on the chip because i have "normal" probes that would likely short adjacent pins but i tested the power chips.
I have also injected voltage using NodeMCU and it didn't change a thing.
Unfortunately i don't own an oscilloscope so i can't really test timings, but my last attempt was directly having a wire connected to U0TXD U0RXD, still nothing @VoltageSpike

@VoltageSpike Does something look awfully off in the schematics ? I'm really confused by the behavior of the chip. The chip is powering the External Flash Chip so there is power flowing through the chip for sure. Usually when you restart an esp Chip the bootloader print some debugging info, but on this board its completely silent.

Why is XTAL_P shorted to VDDA, and the VDDA not having a supply?

@Justme That's actually a mistake, Thank you

Why is the Type-C interface designed like that? Are you trying to power or connect via Type-C? There's multiple issues why it's wrong.

@Justme It's used to power and interface with the ESP during debugging. Can you explain what's looks wrong exactly ?
For the VDDA i looking at the design i think i can fix the current already printed board to confirm that's the main issue.

I think one unknown factor is, what does the XL1509 do, when you power the output 5V from USB, but leave input unconnected. Not all regulators handle that.

Likely the crystal does not work and the chip is missing one supply pin due to a schematic mistake with XTAL_P and VDDA.
Also there are many issues with the Type-C design, which looks like a classic flaw copied by many, including some Raspberry Pi model. You can't connect the CC pins together, it will not be detected as a power-needing device if connected with a Type-C cable. Type-A adapter cables won't care and try to power your device. Type-C hosts may detect it as headphone adapter, depending on what kind of cable you plug in, it does not work with E-marked/active cables.
The USB design is also otherwise a bit dangerous.
The design outputs 5V from receptacle, which is not allowed by USB specs. If powered externally and connected with USB at the same time, this device sends 5V VBUS to a PC and the supplies are shorted together.
There's also about 200uF of capacitance on VBUS. If you connect this to a USB host, the host has to charge all the caps on 5V and 3.3V nodes to 5V and 200uF is over the specs as the limit is 10uF. Some hosts may trigger an overcurrent event or malfunction, as it is not expected from USB devices that you effectively shove a 200uF capacitor suddenly to USB connector.
Even if you fixed these problems, the CH340X can't detect if USB cable is plugged or not from PC VBUS. It might not be intended for self-powered applications, and expects that when it's powered, the power comes from USB. USB specs also require that the USB device, if self-powered, must detect VBUS from connector, so that DP/DN lines are not pulled up as a sign for starting enumeration. Now they are pulled up even if PC is off. But on the other hand, your device back-feeds PC with 5V, and that is more serious issue.
So it might not be a great idea to plug this into your most expensive PC, if it damages the USB port, or completely bricks your PC.

That wrong VDDA Bus that is connected to Crystal is the most likely cause i did fix the schematics for it, i have also added more Schottky Diodes to avoid current flowing back into the usb if someone plugs both by mistake.
For the CH340X It's only used when usb is plugged for debugging so it haven't been an issue for now but i will isolate it's power to the USB VBUS, since i'm already reprinting the board.
For the capacitance & USB Specs, honestly it didn't cause any issue while testing and being 100% in specs isn't my main goal for now since it's only used for debugging.
Thank you !
